# Как вы заставляете себя программировать каждый день?

Tags: проектирование

Как вы заставляете себя программировать большой скучный проект каждый день? Я заметил, что мелкие подработки (один-три дня) мне даются без проблем, а большие, особенно с нечётким заданием растягиваются на месяцы, хоть писать код, рефакторить и дебажить умею хорошо- мотивация стухает.

Comment: Надо любить свою работу и, в идеале, заниматься тем, что вам интересно, тогда вы будете не работать, а отдыхать

Comment: А зачем себя заставлять? Ведь нужно всего лишь писать код, точнее сначала думать, а потом писать. Это реально не стоит того чтобы себя заставлять. 

Более практичный подход. Запереться в комнате с компьютером, выключить телефон/радио/мессенджер/email и выходить оттуда только в туалет/поспать/поесть. Еще лучше найти человека который приносит туда еду/напитки и поставить диван рядом с компьютером. В выходные можно иногда выходить на улицу поболтать с друзьями в баре, чтобы окончательно не сойти с ума от бесконечного кодинга.

Comment: Никак. Оно само прет.

Comment: Недержание кода?

Comment: @alexlz, запор замучал?

Comment: смотря на некоторый код, иногда другой вывод сделать ооочень сложно...

Comment: mikillskegg, вот бывает мучает

Comment: мотивация у всех рано или поздно утихает... надо писать с КЕМ-ТО..

Comment: >а остальное- тупая, нудная работа, от которой хочется сбежать?

повторное использование кода, кодогенерация, нет? не слышали?

Comment: @d9k - хотите сбежать? ну так бежите, жизнь коротка...

Comment: @Gorets - угу, в идеале жена программист :D

Comment: >мотивация у всех рано или поздно утихает.

Очень спорный тезис. Знаю людей, у которых мотивация к какой-то интеллектуальной деятельности не утихала до конца жизни. Причем никто их никуда не гнал.

Comment: @d9k, если рутина надоела, и на ней уже не одна собака съедена — найдите себе толковых подчиненных-джуниоров. Им опыт, вам — более нетривиальные задачи. Потом джуны подрастут и история повторится.

Comment: нашёл ответ лично для себя: http://habrahabr.ru/qa/10059/#answer_43421
жаль, что админы закрыли вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

День - один проект, день - второй проект, день - выходной. И так по кругу. При таком подходе и сроки соблюдаются, и интерес не пропадает, и мозги "прочищаются", позволяя смотреть на уже написанный код свежим взглядом.

Comment: "Фабичный" какой-то подход, не хакерский. Так никакой концентрации на проблеме не будет. 

Вот @AlexWindHope правильно написал, чем надо заниматься.

Comment: Вообще-то стандартное шаблонное программирование утомляет до такой скуки, что интерес к нему приходится вызывать изучением чего-то нового. А любовь к работе - это бред. Любовь может быть к делу или хобби, но это редко приносит прибыль.

Comment: @Равнодушный - завидуйте без негатива :)

Answer (score 1):

Просто отдыхать надо уметь.